# How to programmatically override assembly binding?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, assembly-binding-redirect

I've got an AppDomain hosted plugin architecture. Each plugin is installed in their own folders together with whatever dependency assemblies they need. At runtime the plugins are instantiated into their own AppDomains together with the optional plugin.config file that they can use to specify assembly redirects, etc.

The interfaces for Host-Plugin communication are defined in My.API assembly. The host application has its own My.API assembly, but it is likely that the plugins will bundle the My.API assembly as their dependency as well.

As long as these two My.API assemblies are the same version there's no problem - however if the host application is updated with a newer version of My.API assembly, it would be best to use this backwards compatible My.API assembly for the plugin as well.

Is there a way to force the Host-installed My.API assembly to be loaded in the plugin app domain (and used for assembly binding) instead of the My.API assembly that is located in the plugin folder, which is defined as the `ApplicationBase` of the `AppDomain`?

The usual `AssemblyResolve` events won't work here as those are triggered only when the assembly bind fails - in this case the assembly bind succeeds, but it will bind to the possibly outdated assembly.

I can force the correct assembly to be loaded with `LoadFrom`, but this doesn't populate the assembly binding cache, which will still load the plugin assembly when assembly binding occurs.

One option I've came up with is to programmatically insert an assembly redirect into the plugin.config to force the My.API to be loaded as version 9999.0.0.0. I expect this would result in AssemblyResolve event that I could then resolve using the correct version of the assembly. However as far as I know, the only way to insert the redirection is to physically modify the plugin.config - something I would like to stay away from.

Are there any other approaches to force a specific assembly binary into the app domain?

I guess publisher policies might be able to solve this, but don't those need GAC deployment? Currently none of the assemblies are deployed into GAC. There might be various versions of the application installed and each of these should be using their specific versions of assemblies. GAC would end up forcing v1.0 of the application to end up with v2.0 assemblies - while only v1.0 plugin in v2.0 application should redirect to v2.0 assemblies.

(We're currently using static 1.0.0.0 assembly version so having different assembly identities shouldn't be a problem as long as we could redirect the physical path.)

Comment: [Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info) is a programming language. Do not misuse tags.

Comment: _"...it is likely that the plugins will bundle the My.API assembly as their dependency as well."_ - sounds like a bad idea and redirect configs always a bit smelly in my experience.   As you've guessed, the GAC is one approach particularly when you know.  Odd the `AssemblyResolve` fails.  Is that because of the redirect entries?  What happens if you remove the redirects;  private deployments of  **My.API.dll**; and simply try to do everything with the resolver and a _single_ **My.API.dll** that you distrubute.  Wishing you well. :)

Comment: Also, good idea to make My.API _contract-only_ and leave the implementation in your primary appdomain somewhere.  You should be able to have plugins all running with different contract versions with your plugin system concurrently like you said

Comment: The AssemblyResolve fails, because the assembly load succeeds by default. The AssemblyResolve is triggered only when the initial assembly load fails. The contract-only My.API approach is difficult as people have introduced base classes, etc. in the My.API assembly. These base classes come with expectations of certain functionality in the host app domain. The final option, if we can't force a redirect, is to maintain the compatibility of the internal interfaces that support those base classes. This will work - even if it ends up with maintenance overhead.

Comment: (Actually removing the My.API.dll from the plugin installation folder would be an option I guess. Good point!)